# Exercise to draw a quare of asterisks with lines between them

Tags: java

I'm currently learning java, and one of the exercises is to draw a square with "n" asterisks in both height and width, with "-" and "|" between them.
The user must input "n" and the square should be drawn acordingly.
Example:

```
n = 3:
*-*-*
| | |
*-*-*
| | |
*-*-*
```

My problem is that what happens is this:

```
*-*-*
| | |
*-*-*
| | |
*-*-*
| | |
```

Here's my code: (Can you see what's wrong with it? Should be pretty simple but I can't get my head over it... )

```
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Criar quadrados de asteriscos e de hifens:");
        System.out.println("Qual o valor a atribuir a n?");
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = teclado.nextInt();
        int altura = n;
        int largura = n;

        for (int h = 0; h < altura ; h++) {

            System.out.printf("");
            for (int w = 0; w < largura - 1; w++) {
                System.out.print("*-");
            }
            System.out.println("*");
            for (int w2 = 0; w2 < largura - 2; w2++) {
                System.out.print("| ");
            } System.out.print("|");
            System.out.println(" |");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, you print a line of `|` after each line of stars. But you really should only do that for the first n-1 lines. In the last line, you should just draw the stars, not the `|`.

Comment: I understand that, but I've tried using an "h2" int variable inside to draw th "|" when altura - 1 (height -1) but it screws up :\
I'm a newbie in java, just started ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid printing the extra line of pipes at the end, add a condition `if (h < altura - 1)` for printing the pipes:

```
    for (int h = 0; h < altura; h++) {

        System.out.printf("");
        for (int w = 0; w < largura - 1; w++) {
            System.out.print("*-");
        }

        System.out.println("*");
        if (h < altura - 1) { // add this condition to avoid printing the extra line
            for (int w2 = 0; w2 < largura - 2; w2++) {
                System.out.print("| ");
            }

            System.out.print("|");
            System.out.println(" |");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved it! :) 
I knew it was something really simple but get so confused :(

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to check if `h<altura-1`.

```
System.out.println("Criar quadrados de asteriscos e de hifens:");
System.out.println("Qual o valor a atribuir a n?");
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = teclado.nextInt();
int altura = n;
int largura = n;

for (int h = 0; h < altura ; h++) {

    System.out.printf("");
    for (int w = 0; w < largura - 1; w++) {
        System.out.print("*-");
    }
    System.out.println("*");

    if(h < altura - 1) {
        System.out.println("|");
        for (int w2 = 0; w2 < largura - 1 && h < altura -1; w2++) {
           System.out.print("| ");
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using java 8 you could also make use of the `StringJoiner` which would reduce you prints, and would create the String as you would need it.

```
System.out.println("Criar quadrados de asteriscos e de hifens:");
System.out.println("Qual o valor a atribuir a n?");
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = teclado.nextInt();
int altura = n;
int largura = n;
StringJoiner starJoiner = new StringJoiner("-");
StringJoiner lineJoiner = new StringJoiner(" ");
for(int h = 0 ;h<altura;++h) {
    starJoiner.add("*");
    lineJoiner.add("|");
}
for (int h = 0; h < altura ; h++) {
    System.out.println(starJoiner.toString());
    if (h<altura-1)
        System.out.println(lineJoiner.toString());
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks! :D but I think this is allready out of what we're thaught in class :) but thank you, may come in handy in the future!

Comment: Wow, String joiner looks really cool :) Thanks for that btw doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int h = 0; h < altura ; h++) {

        System.out.printf("");
        for (int w = 0; w < largura - 1; w++) {
            System.out.print("*-");
        }
        System.out.println("*");
        if (h < altura-1) {
            for (int w2 = 0; w2 < largura - 2; w2++) {
                System.out.print("| ");
            } System.out.print("|");
            System.out.println(" |");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :) And yeah that solved it! Thank you too ^^

Answer (score 0):

The code that produces the "|" is in inside the for loop; which runs "n" times. In this instance, "n" = 3, and so the for loop runs three times. That means that the code producing the "|" symbol runs 3 times, instead of the 2 times needed to create the square.

You need to take into account that the "|" symbol should not occur after the "n"th row of asterisks has been written. :)